# How to pass a script block as parameter and execute multiple times?

Tags: powershell, scriptblock

I wish to pass "Write-Host mm" as script block to function "f", and I hope "f" will execute it 10 times, so I tried:

```
    function f([ScriptBlock]$s)
    {
        1..10|$s
    }
    f(Write-Host mm)
```

Unfortunately, powershell gives error:

```
    At C:\Users\engineer\Documents\Untitled1.ps1:3 char:11
    +     1..10|$s
    +           ~~
    Expressions are only allowed as the first element of a pipeline.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExpressionsMustBeFirstInPipeline
    How to correct my script?
```

Thanks for Jason's first answer, but seems doesn't work:
Thanks, but seems this doesn't work, I've got PS 4.0 and

```
function f([ScriptBlock]$s)
{
    1..10 | & $s
}
f { Write-Host mm }
```

Execute this script and it prints out:
Thanks, but seems this doesn't work, I've got PS 4.0 and

```
d:\ > function f([ScriptBlock]$s)
{
    1..10 | & $s
}
f { Write-Host mm }
mm
```

This is strange! A script prints out itself! I've got PS4.0 and running ISE.
Why is that?

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to execute your scriptblock 10 times, but instead you try to pipe in an array from 1 to 10. You should pipe that array to `foreach-object` instead.

```
function f([ScriptBlock]$s)
{
    1..10 | % {& $s}
    # % is an alias for Foreach-Object
}
f { Write-Host mm }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the invocation operator &. Also, script blocks are enclosed in curly braces, so your example would be:

```
function f([ScriptBlock]$s)
{
    1..10 | & $s
}
f { Write-Host mm }
```

Note that you don't call PowerShell functions like you would a C# method - you don't use parentheses around the arguments, you call PowerShell functions like commands, with spaces between arguments.

Comment: Thanks, but seems this doesn't work, I've got PS 4.0 and

    > function f([ScriptBlock]$s)
    {
        1..10 | & $s
    }
    f { Write-Host mm }
    mm

Comment: Why it just prints out the script itself? It's really strange.

Comment: @viksantata Does it print "mm", "Write-Host mm" or "function f(..."?